# getting the sum sqlite (aggregation) android from intent

Tags: android, android-sqlite, aggregate

iam very new in android, i just want to ask a little help about getting the sum of from my database, i use date to filter then it will display the total, thanks a lot, here is my 
EOperation.java

```
public DailyExpense getSumE(String date){
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(" + (EdailyHandler.COLUMN_AMOUNT) + ") FROM " + EdailyHandler.TABLE_DAILY + "WHERE " + EdailyHandler.COLUMN_DATE +"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(date)}, null);

  if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        expense = new DailyExpense(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1), Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(2)), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4));

    }


    return expense;
}
```

apparently it will display the total from database
but ut doesnt show anythng

Comment: How are you storing dates in your database? And what is `date` assigned to? Also, Your SELECT is only a SUM, so why do you have more than `cursor.getLong(0)`?

Comment: 0 is equivalent for id , here is the datamodel >public class DailyExpense {

   ` private Long Eid;
    private String date;
    private Float amount;
    private String type;
    private String comment;`

Comment: The Java model isn't important. Your cursor is only returning one column because that's what you told it to do